# SwiftUI: How to have an array containing Images AND videos?

Tags: arrays, image, video, swiftui

I know there is a similar already posted, but I don’t understand it and no official solution was found for that post, so I will ask again.

I am trying to create an array that somehow contains both `UIImage` and `AVPlayer`. When this is done I want to loop through the array and then display the element.

**Any ideas on how to achieve this? Array of Objects maybe?**

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using an array of enums with associated values.

```
enum ContentSource {
  case image(UIImage)
  case video(AVPlayer)
}
```

Here's how to assign the associated value to the enum value while creating a variable.

```
var contentSource1 = ContentSource.image({pass image here})
```

Accessing the value can be either done via `switch` statement:

```
switch contentSource1 {
case .image(let image):
    return image
case .video(let avPlayer):
    return avPlayer
}
```

Alternatively, you could also use `if` statement to get the associated value.

Below a full example:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

enum ContentSource {
    case image(UIImage)
    case video(AVPlayer)
}

var contentSource1 = ContentSource.image(UIImage(named: "image1")!)
var contentSource2 = ContentSource.video(AVPlayer(url: URL(string: "")!))

var list: [ContentSource] = []

list.append(contentSource1)
list.append(contentSource2)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Wouldn’t i have to do something like this: `var someName: [ContentSource] = []` to create the array? If so how would i then append a new `ConentSource` to the array?

Comment: @Nick I edited my answer adding an example how to do it

Comment: Great thanks. I dont fully understand the `switch statement`. How can I iterate `var list` and get all the values?